# Can iOS apps upload camera roll pictures automatically

Tags: iphone, ios

So today I opened Facebook iOS application and I click photo tools option in your photos menu. I was shocked to find out that Facebook application had loaded my private camera roll picture there ready for posting and it was just missing post content with ready to share. So am wondering is that flaw in iOS or what I mean like that every app can secretly read your camera roll picture and will be uploading to their servers right. After that I went to settings of my iPhone there in privacy section I looked for Facebook and photos where permission was read and write , so just wondering tomorrow some another app will ask for profile picture upload and it will ask for permission you give it and forget to disable permission again that mean this app have got access to your camera roll by tricking you by asking to upload profile picture knowing that a lot of lazy pictures will not revoke this permission from settings manually.

I think Apple should limit this and should never ever give full time read write permission to apps. Apps should be allowed to read picture which use select in camera roll and app permission should be revoked automatically every time use finish up selecting picture from its camera roll , because this is privacy issue that these Facebook and instagram like applications ready pictures from your camera roll and displaying in front of you without your permission one mistaken click would share them to internet and also no body knows that they are not uploading it to their servers. I mean their are tons of apps on App Store apple can’t check their apps code that what it’s doing in background.

Answer (score 1):

In the iOS settings app - privacy - disable photo permissions for the apps you don’t trust.

Then add those apps as receivers when you use the photos app to push only selected photos.

Or delete the apps from your iOS devices and only use web versions or eschew them entirely.